# jq: selecting subset of keys from nested object

Tags: json, nested, edit, jq

Input:

```
{"success": true, "results": {"a": …, "b": …, "c": …}}
```

Desired output, given I want to keep `b`:

```
{"success": true, "results": {"b": …}}
```

Things I tried:

```
$ jq 'del(select(.results.b | not))'
{"success": true, "results": {"a": …, "b": …, "c": …}}
# removes nothing from "results"

$ jq 'with_entries(select(.key == "success" or .key == "results.b"))'
{"success": true}
# nested comparison not understood; returns only "success"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
.results |= {b}
```

Sample Run

```
$ jq -M '.results |= {b}' <<< '{"success":true, "results":{"a": "…", "b": "…", "c": "…"}}'
{
  "success": true,
  "results": {
    "b": "…"
  }
}
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/FvpCrYiFMg)

Comment: Thanks, and TIL jqplay.org, nice tool!

Answer (score 0):

Another way using [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) and [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

### Code :

```
$ node<<EOF
var obj = $(</tmp/file.json);
delete obj.results.a;
delete obj.results.c;
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
EOF
```

### OUTPUT :

```
{"success":true,"results":{"b":"bbb"}}
```